# using libhugetlbfs to allocate pages

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, huge-pages

I am writing a program that needs to use hugepages.

I am trying to use the libhugetlbfs lib for ubuntu64.
I have tried to replace the LD_LIBRARY variable with the name of the installed lib so, and I linked my program against it.

In the my code I call malloc regularly, how can I make sure that I got a huge page and not a regular one?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you do not need to link against libhugetlbfs to use huge pages.
In fact, you do not have to modify your code or even relink the binary.

According to this [HOWTO](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/master/HOWTO)

> Blockquote
>
> ### Using hugepages for malloc() (morecore)
>
> This feature allows an existing (dynamically linked) binary executable
>   to use hugepages for all its malloc() calls.  To run a program using
>   the automatic hugepage malloc() feature, you must set several
>   environment variables:
>
> 1. Set LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so
>      This tells the dynamic linker to load the libhugetlbfs shared
>      library, even though the program wasn't originally linked against it.
>
>    Note: If the program is linked against libhugetlbfs, preloading the
>          library may lead to application crashes. You should skip this
>          step in that case.
> 2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory containing libhugetlbfs.so
>      This is only necessary if you haven't installed libhugetlbfs.so to a
>      system default path.  If you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, make sure the
>      directory referenced contains the right version of the library
>      (32-bit or 64-bit) as appropriate to the binary you want to run.
> 3. Set HUGETLB_MORECORE
>      This enables the hugepage malloc() feature, instructing libhugetlbfs
>      to override libc's normal morecore() function with a hugepage
>      version and use it for malloc().  From this point all malloc()s
>      should come from hugepage memory until it runs out.  This option can
>      be specified in two ways:
>
>    To use the default huge page size:
>         HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes
>
>    To use a specific huge page size:
>         HUGETLB_MORECORE=

All you need to do is to (if you have not linked against libhugetlbfs): 
is run your program as

```
LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LIBHUGEFS_DIR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes your_binary
```

or just

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LIBHUGEFS_DIR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes your_binary
```

if your binary is linked against libhugetlbfs

where LIBHUGEFS_DIR needs to be replaced by the directory where libhugetlbfs.so lives and your_binary needs to be replaced by your program name.

It is also important that your system is configured to support huge pages. This can be done in multiple ways, the easiest way to do it:

```
echo "2000000" > /proc/sys/vm/nr_overcommit_hugepages
```

See the linked HOWTO for details.

Re-linking to libhugefs has other benefits - it allows some segments from your binary/shared object to be remapped to huge pages as well.

Note that the problem is more complicated if you are using mmap calls directly in your code or if you are using custom allocator.

Also please consider just using [Transparent Huge Pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt) which is enabled by default and is a simpler method (but prone to problems with physical memory fragmentation).